# JPA EntityManger.find vs. EntityManger.getReference concerning not existing record

Tags: java, jpa, exception, nullpointerexception, specifications

Could you explain, why `EntityManger.find` returns `null` if entity does not exist, but `EntityManager.getReference` throws an exception according to `JPA` specification?

For my own part, I think `EntityManger.find` - should also throw an exception, cause trying to get entity that does not exist - indicates that client uses stale data.

Comment: getReference() doesn't throw an exception if the entity doesn't exist. It returns an uninitialized proxy, assuming that the entity does exist. And the first time the state is accessed, the proxy is initialized, which throws an exception if the entity doesn't exist.

Comment: @JBNizet It throws:
EntityNotFoundException - if the entity state cannot be accessed http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)

Comment: getReference() doesn't throw this exception. This exception is thrown later, when the state of the proxy returned by getReference() is first accessed.